# How to get back deleted Azure Biztalk Service instance name

Tags: azure, biztalk

I created a Biztalk service (xyz.biztalk.windows.net) as a part of testing hybrid connection for my azure website.

I deleted the biztalk service (xyz) and tried to create a new service with the same name (xyz.biztalk.windows.net).

Azure would not allow me to use the same name (xyz). It gives me this error "the specified name is already in use or is not allowed"

Is there any specific time I need to wait until I can use the service name I deleted?

Any help or information related to this would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experiences with the Azure BizTalk Services Free and Developer tiers, I can only confirm this situation. This is not documented on MSDN as far as I was able to find out.
If this is a URL you where planning to use for a production environment, I suggest you contact Microsoft support.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @jeroen. Azure was having a downtime with its portal on the day I had this issue (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/#history). It is working fine today. Not sure what has changed since then.

Comment: Nice to hear your problem is solved @Adi. I still have 2 BizTalk Service names (1 free and 1 dev created in West EU on a MSDN Subscription) that I am not able to recreate after deleting. I think there is more to it than the downtime you are referring to.